# Cassandra data corruption: NULL values appearing on certain columns

Tags: cassandra

I'm running a `Cassandra 3.9` cluster, and today I noticed some NULL values in some generated reports.

I opened up cqlsh and after some queries I noticed that null values are appearing all over the data, apparently in random columns.

`Replication factor is 3.`

I've started a `nodetool repair` on the cluster but it hasn't finished yet.

> My question is: I searched for this behavior and could not find it anywhere. Apparently the random appearance of NULL values in columns is not a common problem.

Does anyone know what's going on? This kind of data corruption seems pretty serious. Thanks in advance for any ideas.

ADDED Details:

- Happens on columns that are frequently updated with `toTimestamp(now())` which never returns `NULL`, so it's not about null data going in.
- Happens on immutable columns that are only inserted once and never changed. (But other columns on the table are frequently updated.)

Do updates cause this like deletions do? Seems kinda serious to me, to wake up to a bunch of `NULL` values.

I also know specifically some of the data that has been lost, three entries I've already identified are for important entries which are missing. These have not been deleted for sure - there is no deletion on one specific table which is full of NULL everywhere.

I am the sole admin and nobody ran any `nodetool` commands overnight, 100% sure.

**UPDATE**

`nodetool repair` has been running for 6+ hours now and it fully recovered the data on one `varchar` column "item description".

It's a Cassandra issue and no, there were no deletions at all. And like I said functions which never return null had null in them(`toTimestamp(now())`).

**UPDATE 2**

So `nodetool repair` finished overnight but the `NULLs` were still there in the morning.

So I went node by node stopping and restarting them and voilà, the `NULLs` are gone and there was no data loss.

This is a major league bug if you ask me. I don't have the resources now to go after it, but if anyone else faces this here's the simple "fix":

1. Run `nodetool repair -dcpar` to fix all nodes in the datacenter.
2. Restart node by node.

Comment: a NULL can be the [result of a delete](http://thelastpickle.com/blog/2016/07/27/about-deletes-and-tombstones.html).

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the idea. Do updates cause this? This table has 2 or 3 columns that are updated hourly. But the columns which are NULL are not update. For instance a file path column that is never changed after insertion is full of NULLs. Also a timestamp column that only gets updated via Cassandra function toTimestamp(now()) which is never NULL....

Comment: [TTLs can also cause NULLs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useExpire.html)

Comment: Thanks. Running describe table I get default_time_to_live = 0 - I've never used TTL functionality on these tables.

Comment: Although I don't know where your NULLs originated, I was pointing out that NULLs don't necessarily indicate data corruption because they can be legitimately created in other ways.

Comment: I understand your logic, but I can't see where the nulls could be coming from, because there are nulls on columns updated via CQL only. Example: toTimestamp(now()) which never returns null.  Also, with 6+ hours of nodetool repair, the data is appearing back. This was a major bug in Cassandra IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced a similar issue some months ago and it's explained quite well in the following blog (this is not written by me): [WAT - Cassandra: Row level consistency #$@&%*!](https://web.archive.org/web/20161126212225/http://datanerds.io/post/cassandra-no-row-consistency/)

The null values actually have been caused by updates in this case.

Comment: I'm marking this as the accepted answer because that blog post apparently explains what happened here. Still one question remains: why did nodetool repair fix the issue? The data was there lurking somewhere? Also, after nodetool repair finished, some new nulls appeared. Only plausible explanation I have so far is what is described on that blog post.

Comment: The original link has died (http://datanerds.io/post/cassandra-no-row-consistency/), so I replaced it with the most active/hit snapshot from the wayback machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20161126212225/http://datanerds.io/post/cassandra-no-row-consistency/. If someone knows a better link (maybe if the original author moved it somewhere else), feel free to submit an edit.

Answer (score 1):

Check the update query if it updates only the columns necessary, or it does it through some SDK/library/framework (ex. Java beans) which includes the list of all columns in the table. This would explain the NULL updates for other columns which weren't desired to be updated.

Comment: First thing checked. Only two queries affect the table, but as I said one of the null columns is updated via col = toTimestamp(now()) which never returns null. It's been isolated to Cassandra, not the business layer.

Answer (score 0):

Mmmh... I think that if this was a Cassandra bug it would already be reported. So I smell code bug in your application, but you didn't post any code, so this will remain only a (wild) guess until you provide some code (i'd like to have a look at the update code).

You don't delete data, nor use TTL. It may seem there are no other ways to create NULL values, but there's one more tricky one: *failing at binding*, that is explictly binding to NULL. It may seem strange, but it happens...

Since

> ...null values are appearing all over the data...

I'd expect to catch this very fast enabling some debugging or assert code on the values before issuing any updates.

Comment: nodetool repair has reduced 50% of the nulls for one given table sofar. It's been running for 6+ hours.

Comment: It is a Cassandra issue. This normally happens during deletions. In this case it happened during updates to unrelated columns. Not good.

Comment: *"This normally happens during deletions"*. You don't use deletes, do you? *"In this case it happened during updates"*. You have to discover from where these NULL values come from, but I'm currently betting on "I had a bug in my UPDATE code". Put some code guard on your UPDATES,  post some code and let's check... File a Cassandra JIRA bug report to the ASF otherwise.

Comment: There's only 2 updates on this code and it was inserting NULLs on impossible values, like I mentioned, timestamp and now() never return NULL.